# Solr Cloud shard update error on commit

Tags: java, solr, full-text-search, replication

I've deployed an solr cloud setup with 2 shads and 2 slices on a single machine according this this guide: http://outerthought.org/blog/491-ot.html

When committing 500+ documents at one go from 2 simultaneous client, this exception is being thrown by the solr cloud. Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
SEVERE: shard update error StdNode:     
http://newscheduler:8900/solr/core_collection1_slice1_shard2/:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:  
Server at http://newscheduler:8900/solr/core_collection1_slice1_shard2 returned non ok status:500,  
message:Server Error
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:403)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:209)
at org.apache.solr.update.SolrCmdDistributor$1.call(SolrCmdDistributor.java:320)
at org.apache.solr.update.SolrCmdDistributor$1.call(SolrCmdDistributor.java:301)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same kind of errors when I don't put enough memory for the solrj client. I need to put something like in my environment:

```
JVM_OPTS="${JVM_OPTS} -XX:NewSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=1G -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1G -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Xms4G -Xmx6G"
```